ASCII file encoding with 16-bit bytes
According to the C standard, a byte can have more than 8 bits. How is an ASCII (or UTF-8) file encoded on systems with, e.g., 16-bit bytes since ASCII characters take up 8 (technically 7) bits? Does each character take up 16 bits, or are two characters concatenated into one byte?
For example, given the following code:
char character;
FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
fread(&character, 1, 1, file);

If the file is ASCII-encoded and contains the text ab, does character contain 'a' or some concatenation of 'a' and 'b'?

I'm not sure about C standard anymore: I think last or next C standard removes support of many odd architectures (IIRC: more then 8-bit, and the way to encode signed integers). The rationale (IIRC): no relevant since many many years, so just forget. And reading files on such architectures would be a nightmare. -- Note: in reality is not a banning of such architectures, but an as if statement: compilers should handle characters as if they are 8-bit (so shifting if needed).

@alexisrdt, Ignore the C definition of char bit-width for a moment be it 8, 9, 16, ... .  "ASCII file encoding with 16-bit bytes" and "an ASCII (or UTF-8) file" are 2 different files as those are file formats.  The first twice as long as the second.  Which one are you trying to read?

Just because some oddball system has 16 bit bytes, that doesn't change the definition of ASCII/UTF8. So they will either have to pad the superfluous bits with zeros or maybe utilize a 16 bit symbol table in case that's meaningful. Storing two values in one 16 bit variable sounds plain problematic.
Mostly systems like this are DSPs and the like, so in most cases there might not be a lot in the way of user interfaces and in that case no need for string handling either.

Also these are a dying flavour of exotic systems which we shouldn't worry about. Demand for 8 bit bytes and and increased use of C over assembler for DSPs will eventually kill off these oddball crap CPUs. Anyone picking such an exotic part for their project and then on top of that decide to code in C truly deserve all the problems that will be coming for them.

Just because some oddball system has 16 bit bytes...  Now do Java, with its 16-bit char values.  ;-)

@AndrewHenle Java is so far from the CPU data word size that most Java devs probably don't even know what that CPU thingie is good for...

Isn't that the thingie that you use to create your HelloWorldFactory object that you can then use to create your HellowWorldBuilder object so you can then create your HellowWorldPrinter object to access the System.out object and print "Hello world!", if it doesn't melt along the way?

@AndrewHenle "Now do Java, with its 16-bit char values" - Java uses UTF-16 for its character encoding. So, a char in Java is a single 16-bit codeunit, where Unicode codepoints <= U+FFFF use 1 char and codepoints > U+FFFF require 2 chars acting as a "surrogate pair". That has nothing to do with byte sizes. Java uses an 8-bit byte.

First, (unsigned) char is assumed to be 1 byte.
But it is true, a byte may have more than 8 bits, defined in CHAR_BIT.
The "normal" usage would be for error correction bits, like in military hardware with possible high level of radiation.
Packing two text "quasi-chars" in such a byte is not intended, but some library might provide a non-standard area of application. As such a processor might also be something for small embedded devices. A Lundin said, not very unlikely.
Worthless speculation, and mind, you would need non-standard C (1 char being at least 1 byte), probably assembly, and yet we are talking about a C reference question!

fread(&character, 1, 1, file); will read CHAR_BITS from the file.
With CHAR_BITS == 16 and the file uses "ASCII file encoding with 16-bit bytes", then code will read 'a' into character.
With CHAR_BITS == 16 and the file uses "UTF-8", then code will read some character with the same bit pattern as 'ab' or 'ba' into character.

Storing a file with non-8-bit as a byte is looking for trouble. If a file is encoded as UTF-8, and the processor system uses 16-bits as a "byte", chances are the upper 8-bits in each "byte" would be padded with zeros or parity bits, that most users won't need to concern about.
